# How to change the sunlight level (with commands / datapacks) in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft, light

I'm working on a server whereas a fun thing for late December I want to make the whole world darker. The Minecraft sun usually has a light level of 15. Is there any way to lower the sun's light level to something like 8 so mobs can spawn on any block not under sunlight?

Any solution like datapacks, commands, or server plugins would work, but I wouldn't be able to use any mods (it could be super simple if I could use mods, but others would have to download it).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I found [this plugin](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/varlight.65268/) online, which basically allows you to change light levels for things at will, and might solve your problem. If it doesn't, I also found [this forum post](https://bukkit.org/threads/changing-mob-light-level-requirements.86914/), which may also help(but it is a bit more complex). It suggests decompiling Bukkit.jar(or whatever server software you use, Spigot, Paper, etc.), then editing the code for which mobs can spawn in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into ProtocolLib plugin to send packets to players. I don't know which packet lighting would be in but if you use a tool called "pakkit" (https://github.com/Heath123/pakkit) you can watch Minecraft packets and that might help you see what causes light changes (example: place a torch in front of you and see what packet is sent). Then if you know what packets are sent you can modify packets as they are sent to include custom lighting data.